# Image Positioning in Navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm having a tough time trying to figure out how to position the social media icons I've added underneath my navigation. How can i position the images flush to the right of the navigation and push it to the bottom a little without moving the links?

Here's a pic of how it looks right now: http://i48.tinypic.com/34shzc3.png

Below is the layout,

HTML:

```
          <!-- HEADER -->
      <div id="header">

        <div id="site_nav">
          <virb load="nav" />
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/2hsawr8.png" /></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/2hsawr8.png" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="module" id="display_name">
          <h1><a href="get[site.url]"><virb customize="logo" /></a></h1>
          <h2 id="virb_customize_tagline"><virb customize="tagline" /></h2>
        </div> 

      </div>
      <!-- END HEADER -->
```

CSS:

```
/* ---------- HEADER ---------- */

div#header_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    background: <virb get="customize.colors.background_header" />;
    z-index: 2;
}

div#header {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:35px 0 20px;
}
    #header h1 {
        font: normal <virb get="customize.fonts.site_size" /><virb get="customize.fonts.site_family" />;
        line-height: 100%;
    }

        #header h1 a,
        #header h1 a:hover {
            color: <virb get="customize.colors.site_name" />;
        }

        #header h1 img {
            display: block;
            max-width: 300px;
        }

    #header h2 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: <virb get="customize.fonts.tagline_size" />;
        font-family: <virb get="customize.fonts.header_family" />;
        color: <virb get="customize.colors.tagline" />;
        line-height: 110%;
        padding-top: 6px;
    }

    #header #page_title {
       float:left;
    }
    #header #site_nav {
       float:right;
       margin-top: 54px;
    }

#display_name {width: 300px;}

    #display_name h2 {color:<virb get="customize.colors.tagline" />; text-transform: uppercase;}


/* ---------- NAVIGATION ---------- */

div#site_nav {
    display: block;
    max-width: 700px;
}

#site_nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    font-size: <virb get="customize.fonts.nav_size" />;
    font-family: <virb get="customize.fonts.header_family" />;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#site_nav div.clear {
    display: none;
}

    #site_nav li.section:after { content: " "; }

    #site_nav li.section ul { display: none; } 
    #site_nav li.section:hover ul { display: block; }
    #site_nav li.section ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: <virb get="customize.fonts.nav_size" />;
        left: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 111;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
        #site_nav li.section ul li {
            float: none;
            display: block;
            font: normal <virb get="customize.fonts.nav_size" />;
            background: <virb get="customize.colors.nav_dropdown" />;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 7px 7px 5px 7px;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 1.5;
            border-bottom: 1px solid <virb get="customize.colors.background_header" />;
        }
            #site_nav li.section ul li:last-child {border-bottom: none;}

            #site_nav li.section ul li a {
                text-transform: none;
                letter-spacing: 0;
                padding: 4px 7px 4px 3px;
                font: <virb get="customize.fonts.header_family" />;
                display: block;
            }

    #site_nav ul li a, 
    #site_nav ul li.section {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0 12px;
        font: <virb get="customize.fonts.header_family" />;
        color: <virb get="customize.colors.nav_link" />;
    }
    #site_nav ul li a:hover,
    #site_nav ul li.section:hover {
        color: <virb get="customize.colors.nav_hover" />;
    }
    #site_nav ul li.active, #site_nav ul li.active a {
        color: <virb get="customize.colors.nav_hover" />;
    }

    #site_nav ul li.active ul li a {
        color: <virb get="customize.colors.nav_link" />;
    }

    #site_nav ul li.active ul li a:hover {
        color: <virb get="customize.colors.nav_hover" />;
    }

    #site_nav ul li.active ul li.active a {
        color: <virb get="customize.colors.nav_hover" />;
        cursor: default;
    }
```

Comment: Can I suggest adding a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so's we can see what's happening. And, also, `font-size: <virb get="customize.fonts.nav_size" />;` is *not* CSS. Please post the rendered as-seen-by-your-browser CSS, not the server-side script that generates it.

Comment: Can you put an image of what it should look like?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm not sure how to render the site in jfiddle but here's the link to the site to give you a better idea of how everything is set up: http://customjtw.virb.com/artists

Comment: @hofnarwillie trying to get it to look like this http://i50.tinypic.com/33y12s7.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css to the facebook image's surrounding anchor tag:

```
.fr
{
    float:right;
}
```

Like this:

```
<a href='some-url' class='fr'><img src='facebook'/></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Work perfect!